# chat requirements

Tags: discussion, chat, rep-requirement

will being able to access chatrooms always be linked to your meta account or will it be transfered to the respective sites account once chat is out of beta?(i.e. if I have 20+ rep in gamedev or so but only 1 here would that in the future allow me to chat on their specific chat pages)

Comment: Dunno, but now you have 20 over here anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

The reputation requirements for chat are **always relative to the parent site**.

This is very similar to the way the per-site metas work as well, where you must have 5 rep on the parent site to ask or answer a per-site meta.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the way it worked at the time of this question since i had ~28 rep with the gamedev site but when I went to the chat for it it said I needed 20 rep to be able to send any messages there.

edit - also the blog post you mentioned says nothing about chat specifically.

Comment: so will there be a chat.meta for each of the sites?