# How to chat in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, chat

I am using Stack Overflow; it is a very good site for information exchange.

I want to chat with experts. I am a Flex developer, and I want to chat (discuss) related topic with experts. Can you tell me how can I proceed?

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment It's always http://chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KennyEvitt: The link to chat (as well as links to mainsite/meta of the current site, and links to other sites) is in the menu under the rightmost icon in the top bar.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I understand that you want to chat with experts.  Now ask yourself, why would experts want to chat with you?  I don't want to imply that you're uninteresting, a poor conversationalist, or a nobody.  Rather, understand that there are thousands and thousands of Flex developers, and only a few experts.  If they spent their time talking about Flex to anyone who wanted to chat, they'd have no time to do anything else!

Chat can be used to engage other developers 1-on-1.  As such, it's not very permanent, and it's not useful for people outside of the conversation.  Stack Overflow, however, is permanent (thus far), and it is useful for many people for a long time.  An expert would be more likely to answer a question in public on Stack Overflow than to answer a question in private via email or chat.

Also ask yourself why you need expert opinions.  On Stack Overflow, content is king - Whether you get your answer from a noob or an expert, you get your answer.  There's no need to specify that an expert would need to reply, anyone can post a correct answer.

Just ask your question on Stack Overflow like all the rest.

See [Where to post questions asking for expert opinion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92200/where-to-post-questions-asking-for-expert-opinion) for a similar request.

Comment: A very, very fine answer.

Comment: A very apt comment on a very, very fine answer.

Comment: Quite accurate commentary on a very apt comment on a very, very fine answer.

Answer (score 13):

> How can I proceed?

1. First, earn some rep. The amount you need [depends on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60588/chat-requirements).
2. Visit chat.<site>.com (ie: https://chat.stackoverflow.com) and choose a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/603/flex-actionscript)
3. Start chatting.
4. Profit!

Under no circumstances should you use the Q&A format on the main site for chat or discussion. It's just not allowed, and for good reason (see the other answer here).

Comment: How do users discover this "chat" url or app, I'm not seeing any shortcut, or my eyes are bad. Thanks , are there rooms and apps in the other stacks also with "hidden" urls?